# Updating only TTL in cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

When running `model.update(args, kwargs)` in python, if the data is not different it doesn't actually make any changes, correct? If so, does it update the TTL? If not, how can we make it so it will reset the TTL?

**Use case:**

We have a model that stores out loop information for twisted and we have a TTL of 10 seconds on it. The program is set to automatically check that configuration every 2 seconds and if it does not then we want that data to be removed out of the active loops. Here is where it gets tricky, the data rarely changes once it has been set for a particular loop.

I can post the model and other information if it would helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an insert or update in Cassandra, the new value overrides the old value even if it is the same value.  This is because Cassandra does not do a read of the existing data before storing the new data.  Every write is just an append operation and Cassandra has no idea if the new value is the same as the old value.

When you do a read, Cassandra will find the most recent write and that is the current value.  So if your insert or update sets a TTL, then that TTL will override any previous TTL for the columns you inserted/updated.

So if you are writing data with a TTL of 10 seconds, then you need to write the same data again before the 10 seconds is up if you want it to stick around for another 10 seconds.